# Is there a list of living Rebbes?

Tags: product-recommendation, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

I just saw a video of another Rebbe I never heard of and am wondering if there's a list of living Rebbes.

Comment: Googling found me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hasidic_dynasties

Comment: I know the line gets fuzzy, the ol'  "Judaism not Jews" but  is this on topic?

Comment: Tour around Boro Park and ask any mom sitting on a stoop. You'll get a list, easily.

Comment: The question could be interpreted as asking whether there is some centralized registry of ordinations, or failing that, whether there is a comprehensive definition of "Rebbe" that can conclusively determine if someone is one or not. Some religions actually do have, or try their best to have, an official database of clergy somewhere. LDS (Mormon) is one.

Comment: @msh210 That list only mentions the dynasties, not the Rebbes (dead or living).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you edit your question to make it more directly about Judaism and not just about specific Jewish people? Otherwise it is possible that it will get closed as being off-topic for this site. You can see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for some guidelines on question topics.

Comment: @Alex, it lists the current rabbi for some of the groups.

Comment: You have to start by defining _Rebbe_. Anybody can be declared a _Rebbe_ - especially post-humously when it doesn't bother anybody.

Comment: this is a product-recommendation? lol does anyone else find that to be hilarious?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.scribd.com/doc/40091084/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D) is a pretty thorough list.